# How to add new table to existing database code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Originally I used EF 6 code first to create a new database and two new tables. The code is:

```
 public class TestingContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbSet<CallDataRecord> CallDataRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attempt> Attempts { get; set; }

    public TestingContext()
        : base("Testing")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestingContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TestingContext, GenericIVR.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attempt>().HasRequired(t => t.CallDataRecord).WithMany(a => a.Attempts).HasForeignKey(t => t.FKTaskId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Attempt>().Property(x => x.AttemptId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CallDataRecord>().Property(x => x.TaskId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Now my strategy is changed, I don't want to a new DB. I want to add the new tables to an existing DB, say `DevDB`.

How to change the code? DO I have to use `Reverse Engineering Code First?`

**UPDATED:**
The connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Testing" connectionString="Data Source=dddd.corporate.xxxx.com; Initial Catalog=Testing; User ID=sa; Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have automatic migrations set up this should be pretty straight forward.

If you haven't, you will need to run `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations` 
Perhaps do some further reading here first though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj554735.aspx

For anyone looking to update a database with a new table (say I want to add an UserAttachment table to sit alongside my existing User table) using EF code first, do the following:

With automatic migrations enabled you should ensure you have...

1.) Create your new model as you see fit.

2.) Create your Configuration file, something along the lines of:

```
 class UserAttachmentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserAttachment>
    {
        public UserAttachmentConfiguration()
            : base()
        {
            HasKey(p => p.UserId);
            ToTable("UserAttachment");    

            HasRequired(t => t.User)
                .WithOptional(t => t.UserAttachment);                
        }
    }
```

3.) Add your `DbSet` and `modelBuilder` data in your main `Context.cs` file

**DbSet**

```
public DbSet<UserAttachment> UserAttachment {get; set;}
```

**modelBuilder**

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserAttachmentConfiguration());
```

4.) Run `update-database` via Visual Studio's `Package Manager Console`, make sure you have selected the correct project from the drop down, this is likely to be a `.Repository` named project.

Your new table should **now exist** in your database.

Comment: To anyone trying to edit this post to include the Add-Migration step prior to the Update-Database command, note that I have answered this assuming automatic migrations are enabled, hence why I am not trying to manually scaffold this change. Scroll down to 'Your first automatic migration' http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: I am doing the same except the point 2 where i dont want to configure anything extra. But I am getting an exception when running Update-Database. It is ........"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Npgsql, Version=2.2.4.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   ............   
Type is not resolved for member 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Npgsql, Version=2.2.4.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'."

Comment: @vinmm looks like its some sort of issue with the NPGSQL assembly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852359/npgsql-cant-find-npgsqlexception-when-doing-migrations

Comment: i have tried this approach but in the configuration file when i am using model properties it gives the following error: "UserAttachment"  doesnot have a definition for "UserId"  and no accessible extension method "UserId" aceepting a first argument of type "UserAttachment" could be found (are you missing using a directive or an assembly reference?). i dont know how to resolve this i have created my table by creating a class in model it has been created easily but when i try to add seed data using the mentioned method its showing the error.

Comment: Does you UserAttachment model have a public UserId?

Comment: I have followed this exact post step by step, and everytime it results in a StackOverflowException. I don't understand why my automatic migrations are always broke!

Answer (score 44):

Just create your new table as a model and add its entry in DbContext class

something like

```
 public class TestingContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbSet<CallDataRecord> CallDataRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attempt> Attempts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MyNewModel> MyNewModels { get; set; }
```

Then `add-migration` and `update-database`

Comment: In case it helps someone else, I'll mention my facepalm. Make sure you use a property, not a field.  It will only work with the `{get; set;}`

Comment: Ahah! The property vs. field got me.  Thank you @Thomas!

Comment: Do you simply create a new class in the Model folder and then add that one line `public DbSet<MyNewModel> MyNewModels { get; set; }`? Because i tried but it didn't work. It gave error: The project '' failed to build. Do you why this happens to me?

Comment: I tried but getting error 
An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time.

Comment: If you are as new as me, you might like to know the class to add to if you followed Blazor tutorials is the one that looks like this:
    `public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable-Migrations from package manager console first.
2. Create Configurations Class like

   ```
   namespace Demo.Data.Configurations
   {
       public class DemoConnectionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DemoConnection>
       {
           public DemoConnectionConfiguration()
           {
               ToTable("DemoConnection");
               HasKey(a => a.Id);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add Dbset and Model Builder in Context.cs like

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DemoConnectionConfiguration());

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }


   public DbSet<DemoConnection> DemoConnection { get; set; }
   ```
4. "Update-Database" from Package Manager Console.

Note : "Please select the right folder from Default Project Dropdown list"

Congratulation! Your DemoConnection Table is in Database now.

Comment: Hi, it seems you have two accounts (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772608/chetan-pandey and https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782677/chetan-pandey). If you want, you can merge the two accounts by following the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Use the below two commands.

add-migration Seed[Your Db Name]Tables

update-database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).