# Deleted table in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

I'm new to .net and I accidentally deleted my table for my database. Is there any way to recover it, or will I have to redo it, and if so, how do I redo it was built using Code-First. Here is my table data.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ArtistDatabase.Models
{
public class Artist
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth"),DataType(DataType.Date),DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Art Style/Movement")]
    public string ArtStyle { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public string Info { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = "Famous work: "),DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork1 { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = " "), DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork2 { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Display(Name = " "), DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Artwork3 { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new table to an existing database using Code First approach in EF 6 and MVC 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958793/add-new-table-to-an-existing-database-using-code-first-approach-in-ef-6-and-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

In VS go to Tools>NuGet Package manager>Package Manager Console

write -> Enable-Migrations 
and than -> Update-Database -verbose

If you gotta a error try to delete all the tables from your database, dont forget the MigrationHistory and than do the steps above again.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have PowerShell Package Manager Console with the version of visual studio you are using, you may follow the following link

[http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference][1]

Following commands are to be used with PowerShell Console

Enable-Migration command have to be executed first to enable the migration process. This step creates a configuration class file.

**Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ArtistDBContext -ConnectionString "data source={Your source};initial catalog={dbname};integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"**

Add-Migration command is the next step to take the snapshot of the changes that are to be pushed. ***Initial*** Parameter is random, you can have anything. You can modify the contents of the class file created during this step to control the changes that are pushed to Database

**Add-Migration Initial**

Update-Database is the final step which pushes the changes to database. 
      *-**Verbose*** is an optional parameter to see the progress of SQL statements on the command line

**Update-Database -ConnectionString -ConnectionString "data source={*Your* *source*};initial catalog={*dbname*};integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose**