# How to add a table to Entity Framework 4 on a project with no EDMX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework-4

I have a preexisting project that I am updating, and part of this update requires the use of a new table. The previous developers seem to have used Entity Framework, however, there is no EDMX file.

How could I add a new table to this project?

I tried using a new EDMX file, both concurrent and starting from scratch but I end up with lots of errors.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/cc716679(v=vs.100)

Comment: Code first maybe? [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662755/how-to-add-new-table-to-existing-database-code-first). With EF you have two options. One is manipulating your database and then automagically changing your model (this one uses EDMX files), the other is to write your business classes and then automagically chaning your database (code first approach).

Comment: Looks like they're using a Code First model - check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database#derived-context) for some examples of how this works.